# How to configure Application Request Routing in IIS 7.0 for 2 applications running locally on different ports?

Tags: iis, routes, request, reverse-proxy

I've got 2 applications running on my local machine. One sharepoint and another IIS application:

localhost:43442
localhost:5080

I've installed ARR and need to configure it to run these 2 apps on a host and port but when adding a new server, it only accepts a server name rather than its port as well.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new Inbound Rule and it worked :)

Comment: I have this same dilemma. I tried using Http Routing, but that sends me in an infinite  loop. Can you post in detail exactly what you did?

Answer (score 2):

For me, I needed to add a server to my server farm, called localhost.  Clicking Advanced Settings... lets you specify the http and https ports.  Set those to the ports that you would like your domain proxied to.

After that, create an inbound rule for URL Rewrite that matches the HTTP_HOST condition with a pattern of your website domain that the server is acting as a proxy for.  Select Route to Server Farm for the action and select the specified server farm.